# Can a unit of infinite order in algebraic integers of a number field be an arbitrarily high power of another unit?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

Is there a number field $K$ and a unit $u \in \mathcal{O}_K^{\times}$ of infinite order which can be written as an arbitrarily high power of another unit?

I think the answer is no, because a Dedekind ring is finitely generated.  However, I am not sure if this is the correct line of argument.

Comment: Why not? In $\mathbb{C}$, say, every nonzero element has a root of any degree.

Comment: I apologize, I put the wrong thing in the title.  The question body had the correct statement all along.  I was looking for rings of integers of an algebraic number field.

Comment: Also known as number rings. Title should also say "a unit" rather than "every unit."

Comment: Well, "can a unit" would be trivially so: just take 1 = (-1)^2.  The "every unit is a power" requires "there is a unit of arbitrarily high power".

Comment: Ah, I interpreted the question differently than you intended, sorry. But then why is it $\exists u$ in your question and not $\forall u$? And why refer to "an element" $u$ in the body of the question?

Comment: @user2097 Quote: "has an element u *of infinite order*"  -1 is not of infinite order.  This is another one of those things the title said incorrectly.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Possibly...  I am not familiar with the fundamental unit.  Edit: I looked it up, and it looks like this does not work because the fundamental unit itself is not a power of any other unit.

Comment: The title is still asking a different question - "every unit is a power of another unit" translates to $\forall u\in{\cal O}\, \exists v\in{\cal O}\setminus\{u\},n\in\Bbb Z:u=v^n$.

Comment: @anon If there exists such a unit, we can take a the number ring containing just powers of that unit as units of the ring of algebraic integers, and that would be one satisfying "for all"; the converse is also true if we require that the unit be of infinite order.  It's actually my fault for typing the title before typing up the body of the question (which turned out a bit different than what the title said).
Edit: it would translate to $\forall u\in\cal O\exists v\in\cal O, n\in\Bbb N_{\geq 2}:u=v^n$

Comment: By "take the number ring containing just powers of that unit," are you suggesting that given any cyclic subgroup $\langle u\rangle\subseteq{\cal O}^\times$ there exists a subring $R\subseteq{\cal O}$ such that $R^\times=\langle u\rangle$? Also I don't understand what you mean by the converse is also true if we require the unit have infinite order - if we consider the converse of the implication you're suggesting, then we start with a "for all units" claim - which unit exactly are you requiring to be infinite order in this "for all units" claim?

Comment: @anon I think so (more precisely, $R^{\rm x} = \langle u\rangle$ x $\zeta_\mu$, where the latter contains units of finite order.  I might be wrong.  But, for example, we can localize.

Comment: I'll come back later I suppose. Maybe someone will clear up what your question is for me by then.

Comment: @anon So the site is suggesting to move our conversation to chat...  Let's just say, if you can answer either one of the formulations (even if they are not equivalent), I would appreciate it.  Edit: OK, someone else already did.  Very sorry for misformulation!  I will try to be extra careful if I post again.

Comment: I took the liberty of rephrasing the question (in both the title and the body) to what I think it meant to say. Let me know if it's wrong.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, I noticed that, and there was no way to let you know that I appreciate it.  I am only a beginner, and quite often I say things that my advisor just balks at.  I guess I really have to work on stating things I mean properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. By [Dirichlet's unit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_unit_theorem) the group of units is always finitely generated, and an element of infinite order in a finitely generated abelian group can never satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 4):

Consider a number field of degree $N$.
Let $0\ne u\in\mathcal O$ such that for all $m\in\mathbb N$ there exixts $v_m\in\mathcal O$ with $u=v_m^m$. Then $(u)\subseteq (v_2)\subseteq (v_4)\subseteq(v_8)\subseteq\ldots$ must be eventually stationary, so $v_{2^r}$ and $v_{2^{r+1}}$ differ by a unit, say $v_{2^r}=wv_{2^{r+1}}$, which implies that $u=v_{2^{r+1}}^{2^{r+1}}$ and $u^2=v_{2^r}^{2^{r+1}}$ differ by a unit, i.e., $u=w^{2^{r}}\in\mathcal O^\times$. (You had already found this).

Let $f(X)$ be the minimal polynomial of $u$ and assume $|u'|<R$ for all conjugates $u'$ of $u$. Then the conjugates $v'$ of $v_m$ are like $v_m$ roots of $f(X^m)$ so that $|v'|^m\le R$, i.e. $|v'|\le\sqrt[m]R$. Then for $m$ large enough all conjugates have absolute value $<2$. We conclude that the minimal polynomial of $v_m$ is of the form 
$$X^d+a_{d-1}X^{d-1}+\ldots +a_2X^2+a_1X\pm 1$$
with $d\le N$ and - as $a_i$ is the sum of certain products of certain subsets of the conjugates - $|a_i|\le 2^{2N}$.
Since there are only finitely many such polynomials and each has only finitely many roots, the $v_m$ cannot all be distinct. But if $v_m=v_k$ with $m\ne k$ then $u^k=v_m^{mk}=v_k^{mk}=u^m$, so $u$ has finite order.